# How to silence dotnet output "'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded"

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I want to prevent my app to output these "dll loaded" strings into my debug output.
Like:

`'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.13\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.13\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.13\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.13\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.13\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.13\System.IO.Pipelines.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\System.Memory.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\System.Private.Xml.dll'. 
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.13\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'.`

I apologize if this has been asked before but I just cannot find an answer online.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (I found some answers for when using Visual Studio Code but those do not apply) and when I run my asp.net application (something fairly simple) running on .Net Core 2.1 I get a lot of this output which is annoying me since then my Angular compiler output gets lost in it.
I tried fiddling with various verbosity values for the project etc but nothing worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're should disable '*Module Load Messages*' and maybe '*Module Unload Messages*'.

## Option 1

Menu -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window

[image]

## Option 2

Right click on the Output window.

[image]

Comment: Omg I never knew about the option 2 window in all my years. It should definitely be more discoverable :O